# Trajectory of electrons (treated classically) in the C-frame

Tags: classical-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, orbital-motion

This is a classical treatment of two electrons moving in vacuum. In a frame of reference attached to either electron, I found by solving the 2-body problem, that the other electron would move in a hyperbolic trajectory given by:
$$
r= \frac {a_0}{2 \cos \theta - 1}
$$
, in polar coordinates, where ${a_0}$ is the Bohr radius, since I allowed the total energy of the system to be $E_{\text {total}} = 1 \text {Ry}$ and the total angular momentum of the system to be $L=h/2π$. My question is, what is the trajectory of both the electrons in the C-frame ? I mean each electron moves w.r.t. the other in a hyperbolic trajectory, then will both of them still move (in the C-frame) on the hyperbolic trajectories? I know this is quite stupid but my head is getting blank on this. Any help please. Thanks!

Comment: There is no energy quantization for unbound trajectories.

Comment: You really worked in the non-inertial frame of the electron? Why?

Comment: @G. Smith , thanks, I have edited the question.

Comment: Have you learned about how to solve the bound two-body problem where both objects move in elliptical orbits? The orbit of each one is an ellipse with focus at the center of mass, and the motion of each relative to the other is an ellipse. It’s the same with your hyperbolic trajectories.

Comment: @G. Smith, oh! There was I stuck. Thanks for help. 